# File mapping for Django deployment

Tags: python, django, .htaccess, deployment

I have hammered out my first Django site following the tutorial on the official Django site, with lots of googling on the way. The site would allow me to upload images(stored under the '**media**' folder) and have them displayed. It works fine locally on firefox. Now I am stuck on how to deploy it. I have mainly followed [instructions on flailingmonkey.com](http://flailingmonkey.com/install-django-justhost/) to try to setup the production environment on justhost. I modified the settings and reorganized folders according to [this page by the author of "Two Scoops of Django"](https://github.com/twoscoops/django-twoscoops-project/blob/develop/project_name/project_name/settings/base.py). My local file structure looks something like this.

```
C:\django_projects
    +---< my_project >
    |    +---< my_project >
    |    |    |--- settings.py
    |    |    |--- urls.py
    |    |    |--- wsgi.py
    |    |    |--- __init__.py
    |    |
    |    +---< my_app >
    |         +---< static >
    |         |    +---< my_app >
    |         |         +---< css >
    |         |         |    |--- style.css
    |         |         +---< script >
    |         |              |--- my_javascript.js
    |         +---< templates >
    |         +---< migrations >
    |         +---< __pycache__ >
    |         |--- admin.py
    |         |--- urls.py
    |         |--- models.py
    |         |--- views.py
    |         |--- __init__.py
    |    
    +---\assets
    |    +---< admin >
    |    +---< my_app >
    |         +---< css >
    |         |    |--- style.css
    |         +---< script >
    |              |--- my_javascript.js
    |
    +---\static
    |
    +---\media
```

As I understand, I should use '*collectstatic*' to gather all static files(css, scripts) before deployment, which I have performed(as reflected in the folder structure).

Last time I did any web dev was about 10 years ago, and I remember all that I had to do in the past was dumping everything under the **public_html** folder. In the case of Django dev, is it anything different? Should I ftp the four folders(namely '**my_project**', '**assets**', '**static**', '**media**') above into **public_html** to the remote server? Or should I ftp the entire '**django_projects**' folder? Do I need to place '**my_project**', which contains **settings.py**, somewhere outside '**public_html**'? What about the '**assets**' and '**media**' folders?

Instruction on **flailingmonkey.com** does not clearly state locations for the project folder and app folder. I have tried blindly for 3 days and been struggling with static files not being served. I have not tried to place everything under **public_html**, because it seems to me to be an unsafe practice to put setting file there, which contains database credential. Please advise.

This might be a silly question to most of you. Thank you for your patience for reading such a long-winded question. I am trying to make this as clear as possible.

P.S. Other than writing up the **.htaccess** and **my_app.fcgi** files as instructed, I can think of changing the '**DEBUG**' in **settings.py** to '**False**'. Is there anything still missing for a deployment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would not put the django project into public_html.  Normally, Django will talk to mod_wsgi (Apache) or uWSGI (nginx) and serve the dynamic content back to the server process using the wsgi protocol.  The static content (images, javascript, etc) is normally mapped to a server-side directory.

I recommend reading the deployment page on the Django project page: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

Comment: Thank you Doug for your reply. It is a rocky road with the deployment. Justhost has Python 2.6 preinstalled, which doesn't support Django. I followed the instructions on flailingmonkey.com and installed Python 2.7 and Django 1.8. Only when I tried to install mod_wsgi, I realized that it required Python to be configured with --enable-share pre installation. It seems that the easier route for now is to stick with fcgi like flailingmonkey.com has shown. I have read the mod_wsgi docs. It doesn't tell where to put what. Where do you suggest to place my_project folder? What goes into public_html?

Comment: public_html, if I recall, was a per user directory.  I am not familiar with Justhost, but you can install it anywhere.  Python 2.6 will work with Django 1.4, but it is an old version.  JustHost seems to use CentOS for their OS.  I would install Python using RedHat Software Collections (https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/rh-python34/ or https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/python27/).  I would also install the Python development package from SCL since that is required to build some packages.